# Unable to log into my desktop with correct password

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, ssd

I'm unable to log into my desktop for ubuntu.

When I'm in my BIOS, it says Ubuntu is installed on my 500 GB SSD when it's installed on my 250 GB SSD.

When I do `fdisk -l` it shows that my partitions are on /dev/sdb for Ubuntu and /dev/sda for Windows.

I'm not able to login to my desktop with the correct password, or use Guest Session. I've tried removing .Xauthority and `chown` on my $HOME.

Here is my boot-repair-disk result:
https://paste.ubuntu.com/19687933/

Comment: Is this a fresh install or a new problem with an old intallation?

Comment: @tlhIngan new problem with an old installation. This happened after I installed windows on my 500 GB SSD. I had to select the 500 GB SSD just to get to ubuntu to load, which is on my 250 GB SSD.

Comment: @tlhIngan Found the solution. It was secure boot ;)

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.

My motherboard is the Asus X99 Sabertooth. I had secure boot enabled and that was what was screwing with Ubuntu.

For anyone with the same issue here is how you [disable secure boot for newer Asus Motherboards](http://www.technorms.com/45538/disable-enable-secure-boot-asus-motherboard-uefi-bios-utility).